# How to extend the DefaultDuration of Manipulate[] when it has Bookmarks?

Tags: manipulate, export, animation, undocumented

How to extend the `DefaultDuration` of

```
Manipulate[x,{x,0,1},Bookmarks->{"beginning":>(x=0),"end":>(x=1)}]
```

to 20 seconds? I know that `DefaultDuration` is not an option of `Manipulate`, but how to do it for `Manipulate` when it has `Bookmarks`?

Or, make the `x` in

```
Manipulate[x,{x,0,1},AutorunSequencing->{{1,20}}]
```

changing like 0->1, not like 0->1->0 (due to `AutorunSequencing`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Method` suboption `"BookmarkDurationMultiplier"` (default value is `1.5`) seems promising to play with to change the speed of bookmarks animation:

Given

```
Manipulate`Dump`$DefaultAutorunDuration
```

> 4

I would guess that changing the default value of `1.5` to `5` should give 20 seconds duration for the bookmark animation.

```
Row[Labeled[Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
     Bookmarks -> {"beginning" :> (x = 0), "end" :> (x = 1)}, 
     Method -> #], #, Top] & /@ 
  {"BookmarkDurationMultiplier" -> .1, 
   "BookmarkDurationMultiplier" -> 3}]
```

[image]

**Note:** I found `` Manipulate`Dump`$ManipulateMethodOptions `` through spelunking:

```
 Manipulate`Dump`$ManipulateMethodOptions
```

> {"BookmarkAnimationClipping" -> True, 
>     "BookmarkDurationMultiplier" -> 1.5, 
>     "ContentAreaBackground" -> Automatic, 
>     "ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> (#1 &), "ExtraVariables" :> {}, 
>     "DynamicCore" -> True, "HeuristicControllerBindings" -> True, 
>     "InlineCell" -> False, "SingleEvaluation" -> True, 
>     "ShowControls" -> True, "TemplateExpand" -> False}

Comment: Yes, kglr, It works! Good spelunking. Thank you very much!